# Colocar HTML5 para ler um RSS?

Tags: javascript, html5, rss

Não entendo muito desses negócios, procurei antes de postar aqui mas não achei nada, não sei se estou procurando certo. Estou criando um app em html5, css3 e javascript. Quero adicionar ao app alguns rss de sites mas não sei como faço isso, sou novato nisso.. Um exemplo de rss:

http://www.windowsteam.com.br/feed/

Não vou postar código pois não tenho um código para isso, pois não achei nada na pesquisa, só tenho o app pronto, sem os rss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia facilmente ler o XML do feed com jQuery, que tem funções para interpretação de XML. Porém, para ler um RSS de outro site com HTML e Javascript, vai esbarrar em uma restrição de segurança, que é o [Same Origin Policy](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem) (Política de Mesma Origem). Você não conseguirá ler conteúdo de um domínio a partir de outro.

Para contornar isso, você poderia criar um `proxy` com alguma linguagem de servidor, como PHP, Java ou ASP.NET. Esse proxy leria o conteúdo do RSS no servidor e na sua página HTML, com Javascript, você faria uma requisição para o seu proxy.

Outra alternativa é utilizar a [API do Google para RSS](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/reference). Ela faz esse "proxy" para você e devolve o conteúdo do RSS com JSON, o que torna a leitura muito mais fácil. Aqui um exemplo:

```js
 $(function () {
         var urlRss = 'http://www.windowsteam.com.br/feed/';
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(urlRss),
             dataType: 'json',
             error: function (xhr) {
                 var erro = xhr.responseText;
                 alert('Erro ao ler o feed: ' + erro);
             },
             success: function (xml) {
                 values = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
                 for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                     var value = values[i];
                     var li = $("<li />");
                     li.html(value.title + "<br />" + value.content);
                     $("#result").append(li);
                 }
                 
             }
         });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="result">
    
</ul>
```

Comment: Coloquei na página, sempre dá erro, dá o alert sugerido no JavaScript.. Pelo que entendi na parte "de um domínio a partir de outro" isso é necessário quando eu tenho um dominio na internet né? Mas no meu caso que não terei, pois o app é o "dominio" só fará ligação com a internet na hora que o usuário for ler rss etc, não será um dominio (eu acho, não entendo disso), outra medida que devo  tomar para não dar o erro?

Comment: Eu editei o código e adicionei o parâmetro `xhr` no callback de erro da requisição ajax. Com ele, você pode acessar a propriedade `responseText` para exibir a mensagem de erro do servidor. Altere seu código com essas informações e coloque aqui o resultado para entendermos o que aconteceu. Quanto à questão do domínio, não faz diferença se não é um site hospedado em um domínio diferente, o que importa é que **não está no mesmo domínio** do endereço requisitado.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, aqui no site do Stack Overflow funciona perfeitamente quando coloco pra executar. Mas quando coloca em arquivos html e js ele não funciona, apenas fica em branco, sem nada nem alerta

Comment: Eu fiz com auxilio de um site e consegui, porém sem imagem,, vou colocar na pagina do app para ver se fica do meu agrado.. foi pelo FeedRoll